# iOS app rejected for EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV), what does that mean?

Tags: ios, xcode6, app-store-connect, ios9

I have been trying to submit an iOS mobile app to iTunes connect for a few weeks now and it keeps getting rejected. I've done a LOT of reading on what it is and why its happening and to be honest I'm lost and have no idea how to fix it.

I am using appery.io to export that app as an xcode project. It works fine when I test it on my device through xcode, but when I upload for review, for some reason they keep saying it crashes on load!

The crash report is below. Can anyone please give me some pointers as to what the issue may be in simple terms that I can understand!!

```
Incident Identifier: 4A71CE1F-6DB8-4A41-BA2E-03DAD888B0C4
CrashReporter Key:   6adb521327d87924ae77f5dede2428913a51bb3b
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             APP_NAME [196]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/16760F04-A7A1-4AB5-9B86-313E7CB18887/APP_NAME/APP_NAME
Identifier:          APP_IDENTIFIER
Version:             1.5 (1.5)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-09-12 08:41:52.52 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-09-12 08:41:51.51 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.0 (13A340)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
6148914689.551205 CFNetwork                     0x00000001840c8d64 TCP Conn 0x136d662f0 started
6148914689.592359 CFNetwork                     0x00000001840258b4 TCP Conn 0x136d56e40 starting SSL negotiation
6148914689.592636 CFNetwork                     0x00000001840c7760 TCP Conn 0x136d56e40 complete. fd: 14, err: 0
6148914689.592910 CFNetwork                     0x00000001840c8c8c TCP Conn 0x136d56e40 event 1. err: 0
6148914689.649594 CFNetwork                     0x00000001840c8d64 TCP Conn 0x136d56e40 started
6148914689.728396 CFNetwork                     0x00000001840259a4 TCP Conn 0x136d56410 SSL Handshake DONE
6148914689.854149 CFNetwork                     0x00000001840258b4 TCP Conn 0x136d56410 starting SSL negotiation
6148914689.854454 CFNetwork                     0x00000001840c7760 TCP Conn 0x136d56410 complete. fd: 8, err: 0
6148914689.855174 CFNetwork                     0x00000001840c8c8c TCP Conn 0x136d56410 event 1. err: 0
6148914689.870079 CFNetwork                     0x00000001840c8d64 TCP Conn 0x136d56410 started
6148914690.092112 CFNetwork                     0x000000018411e5a4 Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
6148914690.092112 CFNetwork                     0x000000018411e570 Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
6148914690.092112 CFNetwork                     0x0000000184170498 Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001994fdbdc 0x1994e4000 + 105436
1   CMG_Direct                      0x00000001001799d0 0x1000ec000 + 580048
2   CMG_Direct                      0x00000001000fdf2c 0x1000ec000 + 73516
3   CMG_Direct                      0x00000001000fdc44 0x1000ec000 + 72772
4   CMG_Direct                      0x00000001000fd930 0x1000ec000 + 71984
5   CMG_Direct                      0x00000001000fda68 0x1000ec000 + 72296
6   CMG_Direct                      0x00000001000fd9c4 0x1000ec000 + 72132
7   Foundation                      0x000000018585f318 0x18576c000 + 996120
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001848d85a4 0x1847fc000 + 902564
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001848d8038 0x1847fc000 + 901176
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001848d5d38 0x1847fc000 + 892216
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184804dc0 0x1847fc000 + 36288
12  GraphicsServices                0x000000018f7ac088 0x18f7a0000 + 49288
13  UIKit                           0x0000000189edef60 0x189e64000 + 503648
14  CMG_Direct                      0x00000001001076b4 0x1000ec000 + 112308
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000199d0a8b8 0x199d08000 + 10424

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199e3459c 0x199e18000 + 116124
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000199ceca04 0x199cd8000 + 84484
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000199cdb93c 0x199cd8000 + 14652

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199e33c0c 0x199e18000 + 113676
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9538 0x199ef8000 + 5432
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9028 0x199ef8000 + 4136

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199e33c0c 0x199e18000 + 113676
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9538 0x199ef8000 + 5432
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9028 0x199ef8000 + 4136

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199e33c0c 0x199e18000 + 113676
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9538 0x199ef8000 + 5432
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9028 0x199ef8000 + 4136

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199e33c0c 0x199e18000 + 113676
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9538 0x199ef8000 + 5432
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9028 0x199ef8000 + 4136

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199e18c30 0x199e18000 + 3120
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199e18aac 0x199e18000 + 2732
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001848d8168 0x1847fc000 + 901480
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001848d5e6c 0x1847fc000 + 892524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184804dc0 0x1847fc000 + 36288
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001840a2074 0x183ff4000 + 712820
6   Foundation                      0x000000018585f138 0x18576c000 + 995640
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efbb3c 0x199ef8000 + 15164
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efbaa0 0x199ef8000 + 15008
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9030 0x199ef8000 + 4144

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199e334e0 0x199e18000 + 111840
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000199d45e2c 0x199d38000 + 56876
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000198b5a314 0x198b14000 + 287508
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001864c1c5c 0x185f3c000 + 5790812
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001864c190c 0x185f3c000 + 5789964
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001864c3e4c 0x185f3c000 + 5799500
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001864c3ddc 0x185f3c000 + 5799388
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efbb3c 0x199ef8000 + 15164
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efbaa0 0x199ef8000 + 15008
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9030 0x199ef8000 + 4144

Thread 8 name:  WebThread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199e33030 0x199e18000 + 110640
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efe3c4 0x199ef8000 + 25540
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efe5a4 0x199ef8000 + 26020
3   WebCore                         0x0000000196447d94 0x1963d0000 + 490900
4   WebCore                         0x0000000196447cf4 0x1963d0000 + 490740
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001848d7c30 0x1847fc000 + 900144
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001848d59d4 0x1847fc000 + 891348
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001848d5d04 0x1847fc000 + 892164
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184804dc0 0x1847fc000 + 36288
9   WebCore                         0x0000000196445aa0 0x1963d0000 + 481952
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efbb3c 0x199ef8000 + 15164
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efbaa0 0x199ef8000 + 15008
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9030 0x199ef8000 + 4144

Thread 9 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199e32fe8 0x199e18000 + 110568
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efacfc 0x199ef8000 + 11516
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000198b1c074 0x198b14000 + 32884
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186270b14 0x185f3c000 + 3361556
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186270bac 0x185f3c000 + 3361708
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000185f474e4 0x185f3c000 + 46308
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000185f473f4 0x185f3c000 + 46068
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efbb3c 0x199ef8000 + 15164
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efbaa0 0x199ef8000 + 15008
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9030 0x199ef8000 + 4144

Thread 10 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199e32fe8 0x199e18000 + 110568
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efacfc 0x199ef8000 + 11516
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000198b1c074 0x198b14000 + 32884
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186270b14 0x185f3c000 + 3361556
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186270bac 0x185f3c000 + 3361708
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000185f474e4 0x185f3c000 + 46308
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000185f473f4 0x185f3c000 + 46068
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efbb3c 0x199ef8000 + 15164
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efbaa0 0x199ef8000 + 15008
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9030 0x199ef8000 + 4144

Thread 11 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199e18c30 0x199e18000 + 3120
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199e18aac 0x199e18000 + 2732
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001848d8168 0x1847fc000 + 901480
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001848d5e6c 0x1847fc000 + 892524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184804dc0 0x1847fc000 + 36288
5   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x0000000182f71860 0x182f2c000 + 284768
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x0000000182f463a8 0x182f2c000 + 107432
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efbb3c 0x199ef8000 + 15164
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efbaa0 0x199ef8000 + 15008
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9030 0x199ef8000 + 4144

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199e33c0c 0x199e18000 + 113676
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9538 0x199ef8000 + 5432
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9028 0x199ef8000 + 4136

Thread 13 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199e18c30 0x199e18000 + 3120
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199e18aac 0x199e18000 + 2732
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001848d8168 0x1847fc000 + 901480
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001848d5e6c 0x1847fc000 + 892524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184804dc0 0x1847fc000 + 36288
5   WebCore                         0x00000001964732c8 0x1963d0000 + 668360
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000185f474e4 0x185f3c000 + 46308
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000185f473f4 0x185f3c000 + 46068
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efbb3c 0x199ef8000 + 15164
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efbaa0 0x199ef8000 + 15008
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9030 0x199ef8000 + 4144

Thread 14 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199e33408 0x199e18000 + 111624
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001848de6d0 0x1847fc000 + 927440
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efbb3c 0x199ef8000 + 15164
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efbaa0 0x199ef8000 + 15008
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9030 0x199ef8000 + 4144

Thread 15 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199e32fe8 0x199e18000 + 110568
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efacfc 0x199ef8000 + 11516
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000185f4aa50 0x185f3c000 + 59984
3   WebKitLegacy                    0x000000019744f07c 0x1973e0000 + 454780
4   WebKitLegacy                    0x000000019744e5e4 0x1973e0000 + 452068
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000185f474e4 0x185f3c000 + 46308
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000185f473f4 0x185f3c000 + 46068
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efbb3c 0x199ef8000 + 15164
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199efbaa0 0x199ef8000 + 15008
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199ef9030 0x199ef8000 + 4144

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x00000001a06bc180   x1: 0x00000001001e23c6   x2: 0x00000001a06bc180   x3: 0x000000016fd127f8
    x4: 0x0000000000000001   x5: 0x0000000000000001   x6: 0x000000000000003a   x7: 0x0000000000000ae0
    x8: 0x0000000000000001   x9: 0x00000001008197c0  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x00819701008197c0  x14: 0xffffffffffffc000  x15: 0x0000000000003fff
   x16: 0x00000001994fdbc0  x17: 0x00000001001799ac  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000136fa5eb0
   x20: 0x000000018a87506a  x21: 0x0000000136fa5eb0  x22: 0x0000000136fdcb30  x23: 0x000000018a80fbc3
   x24: 0x000000018a8cb6df  x25: 0x00000001001eb4ea  x26: 0x0000000136fb7430  x27: 0x0000000100266000
   x28: 0x0000000000000004  fp: 0x000000016fd12930   lr: 0x00000001001799d0
    sp: 0x000000016fd12920   pc: 0x00000001994fdbdc cpsr: 0x20000000
```

Comment: That crash report is (pretty much) useless until it's Symbolicated.

Comment: ok, looks like that i my next step then, whatever the hell that is!

Comment: SIG segment violation. Please consult office doc for invalid memory access. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/identifying_the_cause_of_common_crashes/investigating_memory_access_crashes

Answer (score 2):

Last week I had a problem in my code which was throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors and I had no idea. I later found out that, I used media player and it was not properly closed. Finding clue for **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** bugs are difficult. You can turn on zombie objects and then might get a better clue.

**How to enable Zombie Objects**

- Select the project in the navigator and go to Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes
- Select the Scheme and click edit, then click Run from the left sidebar
- Check "Enable Zombie Objects" under Diagnostics tab

After this run the project in XCode and you **might** get some clue.

Also, you can test the app in different devices as prerealease build instead of submitting to final app review.

Really hoping that you will get some clue....

Answer (score 1):

(I'm not sure how much of your question has been answered already, so forgive any duplication.)

Apps that crash during approval process testing are rejected by App store policy.

EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) is the type of crash your app encountered.  The short version is that the app tried to access a part of memory that was not setup for use by the memory system.

This part tells us that the app was trying to access memory address zero:

`Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000`

There are plenty of places online that have instructions for symbolicating a crash log. That will replace lots of the hex codes with method names. You will need the IPA and dSYM files that match the app submitted to the app store.  If you used an Xcode archive, then they will be in there.

iOS 9 crash logs need to be symbolicated by Xcode 7. The crash log format is different than iOS 8 and the symbolicator script in Xcode 6.x doesn't always handle it.

The symbolicated crash log should show you which functions or methods to review for possible pointers to nil.